# Show U(8) is isomorphic to the group of matrices...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that U(8) forms a bijection and homomorphism to the group of matrices (1 0; 0 1), (1 0; 0 -1),(-1 0; 0 1), (-1 0; 0 -1). My primary issue is defining a map between these two groups.

Comment: Is $U(8)$ another name for the klein four group?

Comment: It is the units (mod 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $U(8)=\{1,a,b,c\}$ with $a^2=b^2=c^2=1$, since $U(8)$ is isomorphic to the group $C_2\times C_2$. Now send $1$ to $I=(1,0;0,1)$ and $a,b,c$ to the other three matrices, i.e., to $A$,$B$ and $C$. By matrix multiplication we see that $A^2=B^2=C^2=I$, and we see that this map is a group homomorphism. It is injective and surjective.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me understand it a lot better